# JMeter __chooseRandom in Function Helper doesn't work

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

When opening JMeter's Function Helper and try to execute chooseRandom (added with jmeter plugin)

It failed because it expect at least 3 parameters and JMeter display only 2

```
org.apache.jmeter.functions.InvalidVariableException: __chooseRandom called with wrong number of parameters. Actual: 2. Expected at least: 3.
```

[image]

Is there a way to execute it inside  Function Helper?

If not, is it JMeter or JMeter plugin bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you will be able to validate the [__chooseRandom() function](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/#chooseRandomsupfont-color-gray-size-1-since-1-0-1-font-sup) with the help of the [Function Helper Dialog](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#function_helper) because when you populate the list of values to choose from it escapes the commas with the backslashes:

[image]

I don't think the issue will be considered by JMeter developers (however you can [ask](http://jmeter.512774.n5.nabble.com/JMeter-User-f512775.html)) as it's a 3rd-party plugin. Neither [JMeter Plugin developers/maintainers](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/jmeter-plugins) would refactor the function as it will break backwards compatibility.

You can ask around because I might be wrong, in the meantime you can validate the function output using i.e. [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree listener combination](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script/)

[image]